# The distance between barycenter and facet of a simplex

Tags: convex-optimization, simplex, polytopes

Does any body know if there is a method to find the distance between the barycenter of a simplex till it’s facet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know what is vertices, you can find distance between barycenter and 2 vertex. and use tringle properties for $R^{4}$, then use induction